# Sending sensor data from nodemcu to PHP MySQL

Tags: php, arduino, nodemcu

I am doing my school work to send sensor data to PHP. I'm using Wamp server and phpMyAdmin. I have connected `NodeMCU WIFI` and saw a data but I can't save data in my DB. 
The error says:

```
GET FAILED, error no: -1, error: connection refused
```

Here's my code:

```c
void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    int value=analogRead(A0); 
    int heartbeat=int(60/(float(value)/1000));
    float heart = heartbeat;
    float temp = mlx.readObjectTempC();

    String phpHost =host;
    phpHost+="/DogSensor_pre.php?temp=" + String(temp) + "&heart=" + String(heart);
    Serial.print("Connect to ");
    Serial.println(phpHost);

    http.begin(phpHost);
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    http.setTimeout(3000);

    if(httpCode > 0) {
      Serial.printf("GET code : %d\n\n", httpCode);

      if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
    } 
    else {
      Serial.printf("GET failed, error no: %d, error: %s\n", httpCode , http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    http.end();
  }
}
```

```php
<?php
$servername="*****";
$username="******";
$password="*****";
$dbname="*****";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySql: ";
  mysqli_connect_error();
}
$temp = $_GET["temp"];
$heart = $_GET["heart"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO ****.doghealth_pre(temp, heart) VALUES($temp, $heart)";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

`http.GET()` continuously has -1 value. I think this is where the problem is, but I'm not an expert in web programming.

How can I solve this problem? How can I fix `connection refused` error?

Comment: Did you check the generate url? Its like expected? Did you test the PHP script? Does it work?

Comment: As hint. Never post your database credentials!

Comment: Is it okay that $servername contains "http://"? Isn't it supposed to be just "192.168.43.75"?